# Reporting Drupal 8 Bugs

Tags: drupal-8

Are we at a stage where we can be reporting Drupal 8 bugs?

If so, where should they go? Should they go on the Jira somewhere, or maybe a mailing list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the current approach is via JIRA - you can see the existing list here

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17652?filter=23012

If you add new ones label them drupal-8